# Is it possible to do Naryn - Song Kul - Kochkor route independently?

Tags: public-transport, buses, kyrgyzstan, central-asia

I'm planning a trip around Kyrgyzstan. Trying to fit Issyk-kul and Song-kul in my itinerary. I see the distance from Song-kul to Kochkor and to Naryn is pretty much the same, so instead of doing a day try from either city, I'd like to travel from Naryn to Song-kul, make one overnight or two in Song-kul, then off to Kochkor, then further to Issyk-kul. I couldn't find much transport information. Is it possible to do it independently?

Answer (score 3):

There is no public transport to Song Kul, not from Kochkor nor from Naryn. You have to get a ride from a tour company, other tourists or someone supplying the yurt camps if you do not have your own wheels.

You could also hike but it will take several days.